# Turn off right panel magnifier (VScode)

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do you turn off the right panel that shows the full code? The app updated and added that right panel that shows the full length of the code. There's no option to turn it out.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`settings.json` >>

```
"editor.minimap.enabled": false
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can click View > Toggle Minimap

Answer (score 0):

You can change it under: View > Appearance > Minimap

[image]